# OS X - Terminal resets after typing 'grails' command

Tags: macos, bash, grails, terminal

In my .bash_profile I have the following lines

```
export GRAILS_HOME=/usr/share/java/grails;
export PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin;
```

$GRAILS_HOME is a symbolic link to grails 2.3.11 in the same directory, and all the files are intact and where they are supposed to be.

However, when I type `grails` into the terminal, nothing happens. Well, something happens...for a brief moment the title of the terminal window changes from `bin -- bash --` to `bin -- tset --`. After that, the terminal window clears and resets itself.

I'm really confused as to why this is happening. I've set up grails before and never had this issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I know this isn't really an answer to your question, but GVM is the greatest thing since sliced bread and it might also resolve your problem (no need to setup GRAILS_HOME manually).

Comment: what is the output when you type `which grails` in the terminal?

Comment: @dpcasady `/usr/share/java/grails/bin/grails`

Comment: What is the output of `type grails`?

Comment: @carl.anderson `grails is /usr/share/java/grails/bin/grails`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This was due to my JAVA_HOME variable not being set up correctly. As soon as I added `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home` Grails started working.

Comment: I setted to: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: @ErnestoCampohermoso It worked for me. I had set JAVA_HOME to just `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk` and added `PATH` to `$JAVA_HOME/Contents/Home/bin` which did NOT work.