# grails commands not working in terminal

Tags: grails, terminal

I'm new to `Groovy` on `Grails` development.
I downloaded GGTS bundle and started to work on that.

My environment variables
`echo $JAVA_HOME` gives `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin` and 
`echo $GRAILS_HOME` gives `/home/pc-03/Desktop/ggts-bundle/grails-2.4.4/bin`

when I try to create new application in GGTS I'm able to create it, but when the same is done through terminal it just blinks.

When I try `grails create-app sample` the terminal just blinks and doesn't create a new app.

Can anyone explain why this is happening so ??

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: you're sure you've downloaded sdk not just the JRE for java ? can you run `grails -version` ?

Comment: even the `grails -version` has no effect. It just blinks the terminal

Comment: can you run `javac -version`

Comment: download gvm(now its sdkman) http://sdkman.io/ and it should install all right

Comment: also add `-verbose` and/or try `-offline`

Comment: @Frédéric Henri   `javac -version` is giving `javac 1.7.0_91`

Comment: @Koloritnij I already tried downloading sdkman, it is making the things further more messy. So I deleted it

Comment: Related solution for Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255335/os-x-terminal-resets-after-typing-grails-command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix your variables to

```
$JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
$GRAILS_HOME="/home/pc-03/Desktop/ggts-bundle/grails-2.4.4"
```

you do not need the `bin` directory -

but then you should add the `$GRAILS_HOME/bin` in your `$PATH` variable to call grails command from any places on your computer

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @Frederic's answer.

1. Add `JAVA_HOME` and Grails Home Path:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
   export export GRAILS_HOME="/home/pc-03/Desktop/ggts-bundle/grails-2.4.4"
   ```
2. Reinstall Grails:

   ```
   sdk uninstall grails 
   sdk install grails
   ```

While installing Grails, the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable should be present.